Devnet Node not finding any RPC with flag --expected-shred-version 39944
Been running a devnet node for a while not and after the last devnet restart we had to add the flag --expected-shred-version 39944. My node is not picking up any RPC's
Any suggestions?
Many thanks

It looks like you might have gotten your answer on discord already at https://discord.com/channels/428295358100013066/560174212967432193/1258470980574122016, but for posterity, the answer is:

remove expected shred version

